# ANDing the stack pointer

Tags: c, assembly, 32-bit

I'm working on a computer system exam review question asking for the stack pointer offset at various points in the program, and I'm confused about how the stack frame is set up. I've been learning assembly between 32-bit and 64-bit systems for a couple weeks but I haven't seen an instruction to AND the stack pointer before.

Can someone explain what purpose this serve, what would would be the offset of `%esp` after fourth instruction, and I calculating `%esp` correctly? I've commented the code with what I think the value of the offset would be after each instruction.

```
main:
0x0x0804848a <+0>:  push    %ebp                 ;-0x4
0x0x0804848b <+1>:  mov     %esp, %ebp           
0x0x0804848d <+3>:  and     $0xfffffff0, %esp    ;[-0x4, -0x13]
0x0x08048490 <+6>:  sub     $0x20, %esp          ;[-0x24, -0x33]
0x0x08048493 <+9>:  movl    $0xa, 0x1c(%esp)         
0x0x0804849b <+17>: movl    $0xa, (%esp)          
0x0x080484a2 <+24>: call    0x804841d <r>        ;[-0x28, -0x37]
```

Comment: It means to set sp to a 16-byte aligned address. The next instruction now allocates 8 ints.

Comment: 16 bytes actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be enlightened if you repeat your math with a stack pointer that starts at 0x3.

Alignment. Many CPU types require alignment for best performance or for vector instructions like SSE, to work at all.

Comment: It is worth noting that this works because the stack grows downward. So anding out the lower bits makes sp point to unused stack memory.